# Insert float object without disrupting the flow of the text (with multicols)

Tags: floats, multicol

I am new to LaTeX and I have started learning coding with it with the opportunity of my thesis' writing. I have a problem that sounds very specific to me and I am not quite sure if it can be solved, so I would like the opinion of people more knowledgable than me.
In short, I am trying to insert a `float` object (a figure, with `\begin{figure}`) that occupies the entire width of a line in a `multicols` environment. As I know that `multicols` are incompatible with floats, I tried to end the `multicols`, insert the figure, and then start the `multicols` again, with a code similar to this:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\input{./folder/sometext}
\end{multicols}%
%
\begin{figure}{tb}
\includegraphics{width=0.98\textwidth}{./figures/somefigure}
\end{figure}%
%
\begin{multicols}{2}
\input{./folder/someothertext}
\end{multicols}%
```

I obtain a result like this

[image]

which, unpleasantly for me, "breaks" the "flow" of the text. Here there is illustrated what I mean, without the figure to render it more understandable; the first image is obtained using a code similar to the one I wrote before, that induces breaks in the `multicols` environment, while for the second one I used a code that never breaks it. The arrows represent the flow of the different `subsubections`, a different colour for each one of them.

[image]

VS

[image]

For the second image I used a code like

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\input{./folder/sometext}
\input{./folder/someothertext}
\end{multicols}
```

My idea was to insert a `minipage` as wide as the page *inside* the `multicols` environment, but of course that didn't work out.

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\input{./folder/sometext}
\end{multicols}%
%
\begin{minipage}{width=0.98\textwidth}{tb} % I also tried width=1.98\linewidth and width=6.7in
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{width=0.98\textwidth}{./figures/somefigure}
\end{figure}%
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{multicols}{2}
\input{./folder/someothertext}
\end{multicols}%
```

I already searched far and wide in the WWW for solutions, but I didn't see anyone having my same issue. I want to keep using `multicols` as I want the flexibility to swap between one and two columns, so I won't consider using `twocolumns`.

In conclusion, is it possible to do what I want or should I give up all together?

Comment: Maybe, in the place of  `minipage`, try  the `strip` environment, from the `cuted` package (`sttools` bundel).

Comment: Does it "cut" the `multicols` environment? I was actually trying to find something that would do that, unsuccesfully.

Comment: Never tried, but it cuts the two-column mode.

Comment: Just use `\includegraphics` not a float. the only purpose of \begin{figure}` is to take the content out of the text flow and allow it to be inserted elsewhere. But you are breaking the multicol at that point in the source even though there is nothing in the output there after the float has floated away.

Comment: please use `example-image` and post complete documents, not fragments. So people can see the issue and test answers.

Comment: or if you want a spanning two column float at the top use `figure*` which is compatible with `multicol`

Comment: Thank you @bernard!

Comment: Thank you @david! I will try these solutions as soon as I can, and I will provide the complete document.

Comment: Actually, no need to share anything more, `figure*` worked did the trick! I don't know why I have not tried it before, maybe because I was seeing it used always with `\twocolumns`. Thank you all again for the help!